# Typescript multidimensional array type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently i have an array that has this type:

```
handlers: string[][]
```

It has for exapmle: `[["click", "inc"], ["mousedown", "dec"]]`

Now i want to change my structure to:

```
[[{ handler: "click", modifiers: ["enter"] }, "inc"]]
```

How do i define that the first element of my second arra is an object that contains an property called `handler` and `modifiers`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript has [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) which let you define an array with a specific length and types:

```
let arr: [number, number, number];

arr = [1, 2, 3]; // ok
arr = [1, 2]; // Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type '[number, number, number]'
arr = [1, 2, "3"]; // Type '[number, number, string]' is not assignable to type '[number, number, number]'
```

So just use a type like:

```
handlers: [{handler: string, modifiers: string[]}, string][]
```

An alternative approach, when this type is only required on the first element:

```
interface MyInterface {
  [index: number]: string[] | [{handler: string, modifiers: string[]}, string];
  0: [{handler: string, modifiers: string[]}, string];
}
```

Or when the type is only valid in first place using [Variadic tuple types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#variadic-tuple-types)

```
type MyType = [[{handler: string, modifiers: string[]}, string], ...string[][]]
```

Comment: does this work too? `[[{ handler: string, modifiers: string[] }, string]]`

Comment: it would work if you limited the length of the outer array to a single element, like i wrote in the answer instead try
`[{ handler: string, modifiers: string[] }, string][]`

Comment: @Ifaruki Just a hint regarding last alternative: You can already do that with [TS 3.0 rest elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), in case v4.0 is not affordable yet.

Answer (score 2):

Id suggest something like this

```
type NameOfType = {
  handler: string,
  modifiers: Array<string>,
}

const myThing: [[NameOfType, string]] = [[{ handler: "click", modifiers: ["enter"] }, "inc"]]
```